# Как поместить все страницы PDF-файла в Indesign используя python?

Tags: python, pdf

Поиски по интернету дали такие плоды:

```
import win32com.client
app = win32com.client.Dispatch('InDesign.Application')


myFile = r'C:\test.indd'
myDocument = app.Open(myFile)
myPage = myDocument.Pages.Item(1)


for x in range(0, 5):
    myPage = myDocument.Pages.Add()

for a in range(0,5):
    myPage = myDocument.Pages.Item(a + 1)
    myRectangle = myPage.Rectangles.Add()
    myRectangle.GeometricBounds = ["0", "0", "297mm", "210mm"]
    myRectangle.StrokeWeight = 0
    myPlace = myRectangle.Place(r'C:\mail.pdf')
```

Мне осталось сделать так, чтобы из PDF-файла помещались страницы (например с 1-20стр.) на каждую отдельную страницу в Indesign. Я нашел этот код на сайте adobe indesign, но не получается додумать до конца... Выскакивает ошибка, что такой переменной не существует (myPage.PDFPlacePreference.PageNumber = "2").

```
myPage.PDFPlacePreference.PageNumber = "2"
myPlacePDFFile = myPage.Place(r'C:\mail.pdf')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуй добавить букву 's' в 'Preferences', `app` вместо `myPage`, `2` вместо `"2"`:

```
app.PDFPlacePreferences.PageNumber = 2
```

Comment: Cработало! Благодарю за помощь!